# Ubuntu 20.04 Seems to Suspend When Installing on Tablet

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, uefi, suspend

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on a Teguar 2945-10 found here: https://teguar.com/10-inch-fanless-panel-pc-tp-2945-10/

The issue is, when I try to install Ubuntu via a bootable USB, the screen will oftentimes go black and become non-responsive. Almost as if Ubuntu is erroneously suspending the OS during installation.

I've found that adding `acpi=off` to the kernel boot params will work. I've also tried `nomodeset` but I've actually found that's significantly worse.

I have noticed that the file checking on the bootable USB warns about 1 error so I'm attempting to recreate the bootable USB but for some reason, the tablet didn't recognize it because I think it wasn't marked as a UEFI bootable device.

Is there something I'm missing from the installation process? The tablets do seem to have UEFI-enabled firmware on it. Do I need to handle this as a special case?

Comment: Hi, UEFI must be enabled, but Secure Boot must be off. Your USB drive must be first in the boot order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've come up with a series of workarounds that seem to actually do what I need.

First is,

When booting from a working live USB, hit shift to enter the Grub config and add `acpi=off` before `quiet splash` in the boot params.

Then install Ubuntu as normal.

Once installed, edit the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and then make sure the line `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` is there and is not commented out.

This seems to make things Just Work for my case. I hope it comes in handy for anyone else who may be struggling with Ubuntu on exotic tablets.

Also, `acpi=off` can be safely removed from the kernel boot params.